# В каком случае доменное имя пишется с заглавными буквами,например.GOV.UA и в каком gov.ua

Tags: домен

Речь идет о различии в написания названия веб-сайтов и просто сайтов в части доменных имен одной компании или организации,например,minregion.GOV.UA ; minregion.gov.ua; MINREGION.GOV.UA
Как правильно?

Comment: Домены не зависят от регистра, в любом браузере и то и другое сработает. Но чаще всего принято все писать строчными буквами, а заглавные буквы использовать для повышения читабельности (а ля CamelCase). А в чем вопрос собственно вопрос? Ответ в текущей формулировке: без разницы, лишь бы не так https://RU.StacKoVeRFlow.Com

Comment: В некоторых сетевых протоколах стоят ф-ции upcase и там имя домена должно быть большими буквами, например NTLМ. Об этом можно узнать читая документацию к протоколу. В таких случаях преобразования находятся в программе реализующей протокол, очень маловероятно что вы с этим столкнётесь. При этом на входе функционала работы с протоколом будет без разницы какими буквами.

Comment: " очень маловероятно что вы с этим столкнётесь" Я столкнулась с проблемой при заполнении анкеты на сайте. Требовалось указать свою почту 36779282@mail.gov.ua. У меня не приняли эту почту и написали формат должен быть test@test.test

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Домен работает с любым регистром. Обычно используются маленькие буквы в адресных строках и для емаил адресов.

Большие буквы принято использовать для Windows Active Directory для лучшей читаемости `MINREGION/YashinaV`, чтоб сразу было где имя пользователя, а где домен. Но регистр и тут роли не играет.

В текстах и рекламе можно выделить домен большими буквами, чтоб при чтении "по диагонали" глаз за него зацепился.

Может это только мнение, но смешанный регистр в домене - зло - не удобно ни писать, ни читать.  Разве что если домен это фамилия и инициалы.

Comment: Я столкнулась с проблемой при заполнении анкеты на сайте. Требовалось указать свою почту 36779282@mail.gov.ua. У меня не приняли эту почту и написали формат должен быть test@test.test. Полный ответ:Цифры разрушают сайт. Я эту чушь не поняла и не понимаю,что этот формат означает.

Comment: это означает что программисты не читают стандарты и хотят чтоб email начинался с буквы.

Comment: Что мне делать, я не могу отменить свой формат почты

Comment: два пути: или добавить псевдоним (alias) к почте c буквами (многие сервера это поддерживают, если не поддерживает ваш сервер - сделать пересылку с другого), либо административные меры - договаривайтесь с начальником, чтоб он дал распоряжение составителю анкет принять вашу почту.

Comment: Эта почта имеет особенность Логин -это мой идентификационный код-однозначно,изменять нельзя. Договор не прошел,почта разрушает сайт.Как?,Что именно?Может в их сайте есть ошибки. Доменное имя должно быть другое?

Comment: я не говорю о смене адреса, я о добавлении дополнительного адреса к ящику.

Comment: php интерпретирует строку с числами как число и записывает в базу там где требуется строка. в любом случае это косяк программистов.

Comment: Вы правы и это ошибка программиста, а не разрушение сайта форматом почты.Какие мои действия,как им доказать очевидное?

Comment: ссылайся на https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Local-part где написанно какие символы можно использовать.

Comment: Cпасибо, я увидела, что в локальной части почты можно ставить числа, но почему идет разрушение сайта.? Думаю, Вы правы,программисты допустили ошибку. Но сейчас не могу это доказать и я не могу заполнить анкету.